# Is this a scale or ordinal variable

Tags: ordinal-data, continuous-data

I have a questionnaire distributed to the users with the following question from which users can select an answer

Q: What was the project Cost Performance Index

```
Option 1 : 0 < CPI < .5

Option 2 : .5 < CPI < .75

Option 3 : .75 < CPI < 1

Option 4 : 1 < CPI < 1.5

Option 5 : 1.5 < CPI
```

Each of the options have a weight assigned to them starting from 1 to 5. Is this variable continuous or ordinal?

Comment: It is a pity that there was no slider or a numeric box in the form. It is always better to truncate your data in the analysis than in the data collection. A classic example is high blood pressure where studies running for several years risk that the criteria for high change during that study period.

Answer (score 4):

It is ordinal. You do not know which the CPI value is and the answer is not "This is CPI" but rather "Classify the CPI into a category". This category is ordinal.

Comment: Is it ok to treat this as a continuous variable in analysis?

Comment: What is your analysis?

Comment: Pearson Correlation coefficient

Comment: I agree it is ordinal, but I disagree with your reasoning. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

It is ordinal because the spacing of the categories is not the same all the way across. Some have a range of .5, others .25, and option 5 can be infinite.

Note that if the categories are equally spaced, you can consider them continuous. For example, categories 1-5,6-10,11-15,16-20,21-25, and 26-30. The range for each category is 5, so it meets the assumption of a continuous variable.

I understand that ranges of 5's seem big, but think about it this way. Imagine a variable where most of the values range from 0 to 1. The researcher measures this variable to the first decimal place. Therefore, all the possible values are 0,.1,.2,.3 ... .9,1.0. The researcher could have measured it to the second decimal place, but he didn't, and this made the measurements less accurate. It may look like it is a variable with 11 categories. However, the variable is definitely still continuous.

Again, as long as your categories are the same distance apart, the variable is continuous. It probably is not a very great continuous variable, but this is only because of poor measurement methods.